# Godot мгновенное перемещение объекта

Tags: godot, перемещение, gdscript

Есть кинематик боди. Его нужно переместить телепортировать на координаты -6000 и 0. Начальные координаты не известны.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

для реализации того, что вы написали, придется только вручную изменить свойство `position` у  `kinematic body`. в данном случае.

```
kinematic_body.position = Vector2(-6000, 0)
```